# Is there a $content variable to modify page content trough filters?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress dev, I'm trying to eliminate a page title by preg replacing the h1 tag for nothing, but it's not working, is there a $content variable in WordPress to modify page content before rendering it?

This is my code

```
add_filter('wc_remove_cart_page_title','remove_cart_page_title');


function remove_cart_page_title($content) {
    if (strpos($content, 'Cart') !== false) {
        return preg_replace('/<h1.*<\/h1>/m','', $content);
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', 'prefix_remove_cart_title');
function prefix_remove_cart_title() {
    if(is_cart()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```